# I am writing a cronjob, I need a command that confirms that some of the files are successfully transferred from an MFT server to my local server

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sftp, tcsh

I use the following command:

```
sftp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking" -r -P [portNumber] technicalUser@hostName:/path/2022* /LocalPath
```

After I execute the above command, all of the files which start with 2022* are copied successfully to my local path.

I want to verify that all of the files starting with 2022 were successfully copied to my local host at the path set.

One idea that came to my mind was to compare the number of files in the remote host and my local host and if the number of files matched each other, I would verify it but the command "wc -l" doesn't seem to work while using "sftp>".

The command that I use is:

I login to the remote server from the local server using the below command.

```
sftp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking" -P [portNumber] technicalUser@hostName
```

I then go to the path in the remote server

```
sftp> cd /path
sftp> ls | wc -l
```

When I execute the above command there is an error:
Can't ls: "/|" not found.

I am open to new ideas as well.

Is there any particular command which can verify that the files have been successfully transferred to my local host?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact command/script (using `wc -l`) that didn't seem to work with the resulting output or error message.

Comment: I'd suggest using incremental backup tools such as `rsync` that will take care of such things automatically.

Comment: Does rysnc work for an MFT server? I tried using the scp command, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: One could imagine the output of `wc -l` leading to a result that does not give you an accurate picture of your data. For example consider this: @source: file_1, file_2, file_3 @destination: file_2, file_3, file_4 . `wc-l` will yield `3`, even though the files are different. `Rsync` can do what you actually want to do. What's the underlying OS on your server?